# how we can validate a textbox input in webform?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

please can anyone tell me how to validate a text box while iam moving from one text box to another.

it must show an error picture after the text box and it should changes textbox border colour.
iam new to web designing .
please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: I think that might help
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp it's just javascript form vaildation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achieved by invoking validation function on blur event of field. Using jQuery you can inject the event handlers - there are many plugins available for the same.

One such plugin can be found here: http://www.geektantra.com/2009/09/jquery-live-form-validation/

Demo:  http://www.geektantra.com/projects/jquery-form-validate/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yourformid').submit(function(){
        $('input[type="text"]').blur(function(){
            if($(this).val() !="Your matching criterias .."){
                //some error messages etc
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    });
});
```